# Get annotations which were clustered

Tags: swift, swift3, mkmapview

Is there any way to get annotations from cluster inside the `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` ?

I am using `FBAnnotationClusteringSwift` library.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        print(view)

        if view is FBAnnotationClusterView {
            // TODO : What would be now ?
        } else {
            let ann = view.annotation as! FBAnnotation
            let selected = dicAnnotations[ann]

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: selected)

        }
    }
```

With single annotation was not much problems, just simple ask for a view for an annotation, but can not find anything which could help me. Btw. `dicAnnotations` is a dictionary `[FBAnnotation, MyObjectType]` - so that is how I get selected items hidden in the annotation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

After digging in the library code I found that what I need  = To get annotations from a cluster we need to put this `let anns = view.annotation as! FBAnnotationCluster` inside a if statement!
Sorry for asking! Hope It will helps others.